# How to get multiple items for shopping cart

Tags: java, spring, jsp

Currently I am working on the creation of a cart with java and spring.

```
@RequestMapping("/cart")
public String get(Model model, @ModelAttribute("item") Item item) {
        Item lol = itemService.get(item.getItemId());
        model.addAttribute("item", lol);
        model.addAttribute("total", calculateTotal(lol));

        return "cart";
}
```

Problem is that it is only allowing one item to be stored.. is there a way to store on a session?

Comment: You could try to have ` @ModelAttribute("cart") Cart cart` and inside it a List of Items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Problem is that it is only allowing one item to be stored.. is there a way to store on a session?

Don't need to place it in session, you can simply use a `List<Item>` in this way:

```
List<Item> lolz = itemService.get(item.getAllItems());
model.addAttribute("items", lolz);
```

Then you iterate the `List<Item>` with `<c:forEach>` like this:

```
<c:forEach items="${items}" var="item">
    <c:out value="${item.name}"/></td>
    <form:hidden path="itemId" value="${item.itemId}"/>
    <button class="reserve-button" type="submit" name="reserve" id="reserve" value="Reserve Item">
           Reserve Item
    </button>        
</c:forEach>
```